# C Program won't terminate after compared to empty string

Tags: c, c-strings, control-flow

I am attempting to terminate my C program by checking for an empty string ("") but it seems not to work. I have tried to compare to "\0" as well but it was to no avail.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char nameInput[128];
    for(;;) {
        printf("Enter nation name: ");
        scanf("%s", nameInput);
        if(!strcmp(nameInput, "")){
            break;
        }
        printf("Got nation named \"%s\"\n", nameInput);
    }
    printf("All done getting nations!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please put a [mcve] directly in the question.  Links can eventually stop working.

Comment: have you tried with len? If (!len(nameInput)) break;

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Yeah I did and I got errors

Comment: `%s` will keep trying to scan for a string when the first character is a whitespace character. Try `if (scanf("%[^ \n]", nameInput) == 0)
        {
          break;
        }`

Comment: see, this is why minimal reproducible example, so folks can easily reproduce your code and provide real answers instead of suggesting to "try `insert incomplete snippet` and "i tried *that* and I got errors".   no suggestion is immune to ambiguity or mis-implementation.

Comment: @DanielFarrell Well noted! Thank you.

Comment: @IsaacAttuah I fixed your example to be minimal and reproducible. Note how it demonstrates the exact problem you were having, without any unnecessary code, and without anything missing that's needed to compile and try it. In the future, that's the kind of code you should put in your questions.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Thank you sir! I appreciate it

Comment: @Spikatrix `scanf("%[^ \n]", nameInput)` unfortunately has the same poor programming weakness as `gets()` with its potential for buffer overflow.  Could use a width limit.  `scanf("%127[^ \n]", nameInput)`. Better to use `fgets()`.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL what is `len`? Do you mean `strlen`? If ´strlen` returns 0, then also the `strcmp` approach would work.

Comment: `scanf("%s", nameInput);` doesn't exit if you don't input at least one char and then hit <enter>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `"%s"` specifier in `scanf("%s", nameInput);`  first consumes<sup>1</sup> and discards leading white-space including all `'\n'` from the <kbd>Enter</kbd> before scanning and saving to `nameInput`.

That is why repeated entries of empty lines do not advance the scan.  `"%s"` is waiting for some non-white-space input.

---

A better alternative to `scanf()` is to read all user input with `fgets()` and then parse the *string*.

`fgets()` reads a *line* and saves the result as a *string* - usually including the line's ending `'\n'`.

```
// scanf("%s", nameInput);
if (fgets(nameInput, sizeof nameInput, stdin)) {
  // Success at reading input.
  nameInput[strcspn(nameInput, "\n")] = '\0'; // lop off the potential trailing \n

  if(!strcmp(nameInput, "")){  // or simply `if(nameInput[0] == '\0')
    break;
  }
  ...
```

---

> have tried to compare to "\0" as well but it was to no avail.

`if(!strcmp(nameInput, ""))` and `if(!strcmp(nameInput, "\0"))` do the same thing.  `strcmp()` is comparing *strings*.

`""` is a *string literal* of 1 `char`: the *null character*.
`"\0"` is a *string literal* of 2 `char`: two *null characters*.
The *string* compare stops at the first *null character*.

---

`"%s"` by itself also lacks a width limit.  Code has no safe guard against input like "BlahBlah...(120_some_more)Blah" and can lead to *undefined behavior* due a buffer overrun of `char nameInput[128];`.  Code could use `"%127s"` to prevent that, yet that only handles one of the short-comings of `scanf()`.

---

<sup>1</sup>

> Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier. C17dr § 7.21.6.2 8

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly but it stops and does not execute the rest of my program. Is there a way I can avoid that?

Comment: @IsaacAttuah Does you code use `fgets()` to read all user input - or is there a lurking `scanf()` remaining someplace?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I resolved to use fgets() and repositioned it to fit my code. It worked now. Thank you so much

Comment: @IsaacAttuah you should use the check-mark to mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that it won't terminate, it is awaiting the input that wasn't (yet) typed in.

`scanf` is not using the right pattern string to scan in anything (including nothing) before the carriage return.  You'll need to look into `scanf` patterns, and alter your pattern from "%s" to something that `scanf` will accept as input.

If you test out your program, you will see that after pressing "enter" you can type in a word and press enter again, and since you now have a word in the input, the `scanf` picks it up (discarding the whitespace, as it should with "%s").